# Postfix not delivering messages (554 Client host rejected: Access denied)

Tags: email, postfix

Messages from localhost is working normally, but when I try to send mail from i.e. gmail to my domain (as in virtual domain mapping) postfix is denying it with error (554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied).

main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = ***

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = *** my hostname ***
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

virtual_alias_domains = *** my virtual alias domains ***
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:private/policy
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, permit
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject_rbl_client relays.ordb.org, reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org, reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org, check_policy_service unix:private/spfpolicy, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Answer (score 6):

This setting:

> smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject

(combined my `mynetworks` being set to `localhost`) tells that non-local connection attempts must be rejected.

If you want to accept mail from the outside, don't do that, leave `smtpd_client_restrictions` to its empty default value.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check: is amavisd running?  In a typical setup, postfix sends messages over to spamassassin to check for viruses.  I got the message in the question when amavisd would not start up, as it was expecting to talk to an ipv6 network, and that is disabled in this site.